# Customize UINavigationBar in iOS 5 strange behaviour

Tags: ios5, uinavigationcontroller, ios6, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

Here is a very strange iOS 5 behaviour (same in iOS 6). I'm customizing the appearance of a  UINavigationBar with a UIImage as shown below.
[image: UIImage used to customize the UINavigationBar]
The following code is used at application startup:

```
// Customize the UINavigation and UITabbar appearance here
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationTitleBackground.png"]
                              forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CustomTabbar.png"]];
```

The end result is what I expect for the first 4 tabs of my UITabbar items like this:
[image: A Tabbar selected]

The lighting comes from the top of the app. But, when selecting the More tab and all the other sections, the UINavigationBar look becomes flipped upside down like this:

[image: Flipped upside down image]

Does somebody know why? What could be the cause of this? If you look carefully, the UIImage I'm using is actuallty flipped upside down in order to get the desired result... but when selecting the More UITabbar item and the following section, it gets displayed as it is really in the .png file but it is not the desired result as I ant the lighting to come from the top of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I would love to answer your question, however when I create a new project with the image you have used I get exactly what I would expect. All five UINavigationController's UINavigationBar has the background which looks exactly like the image you have.

If you want the light coming from the top you should vertically reflect the image being used to customize it.